# Microsoft excel you have entered too many arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make a function to show if cell values are equal to show 'Paid' if not show 'Pending' and if the cell value is blank to show 'Empty' but I kept getting to many arguments error in MS Excel.

```
=IF(F7=$E$7,"Paid","Pending",if(F7="","Empty"))
```

Comment: `=SWITCH(1+(F7=$E$7)+2*(F7=""), "Pending", "Paid", "Empty", "Empty")`

Answer (score 2):

You were close, this will work:

```
=IF(F7="","Empty",IF(F7=$E$7,"Paid","Pending"))
```

Check out the below link for some learning refs.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/06/06/excel-nested-if-statement/

Comment: Yeah it has to be this way around to handle blank cells properly. The OP's original formula would call everything "Pending" if it wasn't Paid, including blank cells!

Answer (score 1):

You are adding too many arguments
Try this

```
If(f7=$e$7,"Paid",If(f7="","empty","Pending"))
```

There are only three things in an if
1. Condition
2. Then statement
3. Else statement

Your are addinf if at the fourth position. Try adding another if at the third position after the comma where you wrote Pending.